Azure Web Service Angular Deployment in IntelliJ
I have created an Angular 18 project in IntelliJ and now want to deploy it to an Azure App Service/Web App. I have therefore created a web app in the Azure portal with a Node20 runtime. Now I have installed the Azure Web Service Plugin for IntelliJ and logged in. When I select the project I just created, it only lets me deploy Java artifacts (Invalid Data: Invalid target, please select a web app with Java runtime). What am I doing wrong here? The whole thing looks much simpler on the many YouTube videos. They only ever build the project and select the folder in the dist directory and the rest happens automatically.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea You can report such issues to the vendor.

@Andreas Are you deploying your app to Azure web app windows or Linux?

Forgive my ignorance, but isn’t IDEA a Java/JVM-based language IDE? Why would you use it to develop an Angular application, or expect it to include functionality (either out of the box or via extensions) that support any other language?

That aside, there are a number of other ways to deploy your application to Azure App Service that are not an extension in an IDE. Have you tried any other methods, like deploying from a version control repository or a pre-built ZIP file? What research have you done so far, and why does what you’ve turned up not meet your requirements?

Did it finally with moving my repo to github and connect my repo with a CI/CD pipeline.. now everythink works fine for me! :)

@esqew thank you for your comments
Deploying an Angular app to Azure App Service through IntelliJ is not possible because when I select the Angular project in the Artifact, it takes the Angular files with the Java runtime version.

So, it's not possible to deploy angular app to azure through IntelliJ Idea. Instead, I deployed the angular app to azure through GitHub.

I Push the Angular files to GitHub repository.
I Selected GitHub as Source in the Deployment section of the Azure Web app.



I Sign in to GitHub and I fill the Required Details as shown below.



I used Authentication type to Basic authentication, but you can use User assigned identity.



For Basic authentication I enabled the SCM Basic Auth Publishing.


Below is my GitHub Workflow File:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - kaangularapp6
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build 
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kaangularapp6'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<key> }}

It is Successfully Deployed to Azure App Service.

I added the below command to the Startup Command in the Configuration section of Azure Web App.
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/<WebAppName>/browser --no-daemon --spa


Azure App Service Output:

